# Debain jessie Empty PHP session variables

Tags: php, debian, apache2.4, debian-jessie

I am using Debian jessie

I installed apache 2.4 and php 7.0 but the problem that I have is that the variables are always while I put the instruction session_start () in all the pages Thank you for help me please

Comment: Did you try to enable php logging and error_reporting()?

Comment: Ok I'll try this to see

Comment: The error_reporting is already enabled ==> error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

Comment: Can you give some sample code where you have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no php guru but I think you could try to save the session vars into a static variable, and then check the output of that var to see if it's empty or not. There are probably ways of debugging php scripts and see what's wrong but I can't help you with that.

If I were you I would also check the permissions for `/var/lib/php/session`. That folder is used to save temporary session vars used/generated by php. If let's say your apache is running as nobody or www-data or apache, set the proper ownership for that folder according to your apache user.

```
ps aufx | grep httpd
```

First entry on the left would be the user. Remember that user and issue a:

```
chown apacheuser:apacheuser /var/lib/php/session
```

Restart apache (`systemctl restart httpd`) and try again and see if that works!

Comment: Hi To make sure of the tests I create two files index.php and index2.php
Where I initialize a first variable in the first and that indexed in the second page but it did not work.

For the / var / lib / php / session folder does not exist
  Cd / var / lib / php / session
-bash: cd: / var / lib / php / session: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you sure you have installed php correctly?! Do you have a `php.conf` file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d` ?